# Changing the format of timestamp in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I could use some help, please.

I need to convert timestamps in a .vtt file from the following:

**From old format: 
78:08.706 --> 78:18.550**

**To new format: 
01:18:08.706 --> 01:18:18.550**

How can I do this?

I am new to Python.

Comment: 1.  Read here:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior   2. Try something    3. Profit!

Comment: Please show what you've tried and describe how exactly it's failing. Include full traceback if it's throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Parse out the `MM:ss.sss` values, then use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to do the conversion:

```
times = ['78:08.706', '78:18.550']

import datetime, re

for t in times:
    timept = re.split(r'[:.]+', t)
    m, s, ss = list(map(int, timept))
    newfmt = datetime.timedelta(minutes=m, seconds=s, milliseconds=ss)
    print(newfmt)
```

output:

```
1:18:08.706000
1:18:18.550000
```